# IOstream: Работа с блоком памяти без копирования данных

Tags: c++

Добрый день, возникла потребность работы с определенным блоком памяти через интерфейс **istream**, без копирования этих данных. Почитал справку по потокам здесь: [www.cplusplus.com](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/), однако так и не разобрался, что мне делать.

Я полагаю, что нужно создать объект класса **istringstream** и ассоциировать буфер с конкретным блоком памяти? Если это верно, то как это сделать? Буфер является закрытым членом, да и я увидел только метод **rdbuf()** для чтения адреса буфера, как определить указатель на буфер, я так и не понял... Словом, у меня нет идей, что мне делать, буду благодарен за помощь и подсказки.

Update:
Вот, что я сделал, "чтобы заработало прямо сейчас":

```
HRSRC hRes=FindResource(0,L"coordsx",RT_RCDATA);
HGLOBAL hGlob=LoadResource(0,hRes);
unsigned int sz = SizeofResource(0,hRes);
std::string ts((char*)hGlob,sz);
std::istringstream ins(ts,std::ios_base::in|std::ios_base::binary);
```

**ins** тут является целевым объектом, он обладает интерфейсом **istream**, что и требуется в моей ситуации, но насколько я понимаю, в этом процессе происходит аж дважды лишнее копирование данных - **простая область памяти => std::string => std::stringbuf**, вот мне и хочется как-нибудь малой кровью обойтись без лишних копирований...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если не писать свою обертку, то вполне может сойти решение из [**boost::iostreams**](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/libs/iostreams/doc/classes/array.html)

*В свое время, когда я реализовывал `memory-based` сериализацию, у меня использовался код следующего типа:*

```
// See the following sample powered by 'boost::iostreams' library:
// ---------------------------------------------------------------

// Create a stream based on 'std::vector' back inserter.
typedef boost::iostreams::stream<
    boost::iostreams::back_insert_device<std::vector<char> > > Stream;

serialize(object, Stream(std::vector<char>()), GzipCompressor());

// The same technique could be applied for deserialization from
// array-like containers:
// ------------------------------------------------------------

// Create a stream that iterates over a sequence and use it in
// the object loading wrapper.
typedef boost::iostreams::stream<
    boost::iostreams::array_source> Stream;

deserialize(object, Stream(&*source.begin(), source.size()), GzipCompressor());
```

Comment: ух, значит, по поводу буста интуиция меня не подвела ))

Answer (score 3):

Мне кажется, если уж так хочется сложностей, надо писать собственный потоковый буфер и далее ассоциировать его с файловым потоком. Для написания буфера главное соблюсти интерфейс. Он хорошо описан у Джосаттиса в "С++. Стандартная библиотека", гл. 13.

Еще можно покопаться в Boost.Iostreams. Может, там что подходящее найдется.

Comment: Природа проблемы в том, что данные были перенесены из внешнего файла в ресурсы. Я вижу два пути, первый - загрузить ресурс в память и сделать то, что-то типа того, что я описал в вопросе, второй - получить смещение данных ресурса в файле и отработать с ними через ifstream, открыв им непосредственно исполняемый файл... может быть лучше использовать этот второй способ?

Comment: Ну, Вам виднее. Попробуйте, поэкспериментируйте. Я же не могу так вот издалека видеть все нюансы этой проблемы.

Comment: Вам в любом случае нужно грузить данные в память.

Comment: конечно, я и сам в этом ни секунды не сомневался